# PDF of $P(B_1 + B_2 > t)$ where $B \sim \mathrm{expo}(\lambda)$

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I am trying to dervie the PDF of $P(B_1 + B_2 > t)$  where $B \sim \mathrm{expo}(\lambda)$.i.e. the probability that the waiting time of two sucessive draws from a exponential distribution will be larger than some time $t$. But I seem to be making a logical error somewhere as the result diverges.

$$P(B_1 + B_2 > t) \\
= P(B_1 > t - B_2) \\
= 1 - P(B_1 < t - B_2)$$

Plugging in the CDF of the exponential

$$ = 1 - (1 - e^{-\lambda(t - B_2)}) \\
= e^{-\lambda(t - B_2)}
$$

Conditioning over all $B_2$

$$
\int_0^\infty P(B_1 < t - B_2 | B_2 = b) P(b) \ db \\
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda(t - b)} \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda b} \  db \\
= \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \ db
$$

Which diverges. I am obviously making a error somewhere but cannot for the life of me see where. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pdf" of $P(B_{1}+B_{2}>t)$? $P(B_{1}+B_{2}>t)$ is not a random variable. It's just a real number. Just say that you want to find $P(B_{1}+B_{2}>t)$.

Comment: Also, mention if $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ are independent or not. The expression $P(B_{1}<t-B_{2})=1-(1-e^{\lambda(t-B_{2})})$ makes no sense. The right hand side is a random variable and the lhs is a constant real number. You should write $P(B_{1}<t-B_{2}|B_{2})=1-(1-e^{\lambda(t-B_{2})})$ or $P(B_{1}<t-B_{2}|B_{2}=b)=1-(1-e^{\lambda(t-b)})$ by abusing notation.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.GandalfSauron for the useful feedback, I will not edit the question so the history is maintained, but will take this on board to avoid similar category errors in future.

Comment: The sum of independent exponential variables with the same mean is Erlang distributed, a special case of the gamma distribution. See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ P(B_1 < t - B_2 | B_2 = b)=\begin{cases}1-e^{-\lambda(t-b)},\;t\ge b\\0,\qquad\quad\qquad t<b\end{cases}$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty P(B_1+B_2>t | B_2 = b) f(b) \ db \\
&=\int_0^\infty \left[1-P(B_1 < t - B_2 | B_2 = b)\right] f(b) \ db \\
&=\int_0^t e^{-\lambda(t - b)} \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda b} \  db +\int_t^\infty f(b)db\\
&= \lambda \int_0^t e^{-\lambda t} \ db+1-(1-e^{-\lambda t})\\
&= \lambda te^{-\lambda t}+e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$P(B_1<t-B_2)=1-e^{-\lambda (t-B_2)}$ is valid only when $t-B_2>0$ or $B_2<t$. Your final integral is, therefore, from $0$ to $t$ instead of $0$ to $\infty$.